# How to refactor this code and return a generic object?

Tags: c#, generics

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to factor out some common code in my Matrix class hierarchy.  I have an abstract Matrix class and concrete Matrix4, Matrix3, Matrix2 classes.
I've pruned down the code below (possibly removing too much, this might not actually compile).

My problem is that I have a Submatrix() method on the concrete classes that returns a different type depending on the object calling it.  A Matrix4 returns a Matrix3, and a Matrix3 returns a Matrix2.  Otherwise I've written the algorithm generically and feels like it can be refactored to the base class (forgive the messiness of that algorithm, that's my first naive pass).

E.g. I'm thinking I'd be able to do something like this from the Matrix4 class:

```cs
    public Matrix3 Submatrix(int removeRow, int removeCol)
    {
        return Matrix.Submatrix<Matrix3>(removeRow, removeCol, 4);
    }
```

**Is there a way to `new` a MatrixN in the base class**, without doing weird/slow reflection stuff?

```cs
using System;

public abstract class Matrix : IEquatable<Matrix>
{
    protected double[,] data;

    abstract protected int size { get; }

    public Matrix(double[,] data)
    {
        if (data.GetLength(0) != size || data.GetLength(1) != size) {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"The provided 2D array needs to have a length of {size} "+
                "in both dimensions.");
        }
        this.data = data;
    }

    public double this[int x, int y] => this.data[x, y];

    public static T Submatrix<T>(int removeRow, int removeCol, int size)
    {
        // TODO refactor Matrix4 & Matrix3 Submatrix() to here, but I don't think you can do this:
        return new T();
    }
}

public class Matrix4 : Matrix
{
    protected override int size => 4;

    public Matrix4(double[,] data) : base(data)
    {
        // Do nothing, calling base class.
    }

    public Matrix3 Submatrix(int removeRow, int removeCol)
    {
        if (removeRow > size - 1 || removeCol > size - 1) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot remove a row or column " +
                $"outside the size of the matrix ({size})");
        }

        double[,] result = new double[size - 1, size - 1];
        int skippedRows = 0;
        int skippedcols = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x += 1) {
            if (x == removeRow) {
                skippedRows += 1;
                continue;
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y += 1) {
                if (y == removeCol) {
                    skippedcols += 1;
                    continue;
                }
                result[x - skippedRows, y - skippedcols] = data[x, y];
            }
            skippedcols = 0;
        }

        return new Matrix3(result);
    }
}

public class Matrix3 : Matrix
{
    protected override int size => 3;

    public Matrix3(double[,] data) : base(data)
    {
        // Do nothing, calling base class.
    }
    
    public Matrix2 Submatrix(int removeRow, int removeCol)
    {
        if (removeRow > size - 1 || removeCol > size - 1) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot remove a row or column " +
                $"outside the size of the matrix ({size})");
        }

        double[,] result = new double[size - 1, size - 1];
        int skippedRows = 0;
        int skippedcols = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x += 1) {
            if (x == removeRow) {
                skippedRows += 1;
                continue;
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y += 1) {
                if (y == removeCol) {
                    skippedcols += 1;
                    continue;
                }
                result[x - skippedRows, y - skippedcols] = data[x, y];
            }
            skippedcols = 0;
        }

        return new Matrix2(result);
    }
}

public class Matrix2 : Matrix
{
    protected override int size => 2;

    public Matrix2(double[,] data) : base(data)
    {
        // Do nothing, calling base class.
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is too open-ended to be appropriate for Stack Overflow. That said, frankly it's not clear why you want different concrete classes for each size. I agree with the answer proposing just a single `Matrix` class. Even if you feel a need for the individual types, the _implementation_ can still be done in a single class, parameterized by the matrix size. In any case, there are lots of different ways to approach the problem, and no clear way to understand which is the way that would answer _your_ question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I responded to his question about the design choice, and it's a [common pattern](https://github.com/search?q=matrix4&type=code) to have concrete Matrix sizes as types.  If you ignore my extra context, it's really just a question about how to `new` a type generically.

Answer (score 0):

You may have simplified too much, not because of compilation issues, but because it doesn't make sense to make distinct concrete classes in your case as presented.

Make `Matrix` non abstract and then set the size based on the input during construction.  Then, when submatrixing, the size will automatically decrement.

If you have more solid reasons to create concrete classes and the sizing was just a way to come up with concrete instances quickly just to produce examples, then I would edit the question to better demonstrate why you're looking for an abstraction and why you still need to output concrete instances.  If you still do, maybe looking into a [factory pattern](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/) would be relevant to you.

```
public class Matrix : IEquatable<Matrix> {

    double[,] data;

    int size { get; private set; }

    public Matrix(double[,] data) {
        if (data.GetLength(0) != data.GetLength(1))
            throw new ArgumentException("The provided 2D array is not square.");
        this.data = data;
        this.size = data.GetLength(0);
    }

    public double this[int x, int y] => this.data[x, y];

    public Matrix Submatrix(
        int removeRow, 
        int removeCol
    ) {

       if (removeRow > size - 1 || removeCol > size - 1) 
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Cannot remove a row or column " +
                $"outside the size of the matrix ({size})"
            );

        double[,] result = new double[size - 1, size - 1];
        int skippedRows = 0;
        int skippedcols = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x += 1) {
            if (x == removeRow) {
                skippedRows += 1;
                continue;
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y += 1) {
                if (y == removeCol) {
                    skippedcols += 1;
                    continue;
                }
                result[x - skippedRows, y - skippedcols] = data[x, y];
            }
            skippedcols = 0;
        }

        return new Matrix(result);

    }

    // ... other methods, particularly ones implementing IEquatable

}
```

Comment: Yes I hear that but pretend I have a great reason for having concrete MatrixN classes, how can I factor out just the common Submatrix code to the base class?
(There are some differences like calculating the determinant is different for different sizes, which yes could be generalized in a base class, but I currently like how explicit those differences are right now.  I also like that I know I'm dealing with a Matrix4 in client code just by looking at the type.)

Answer (score 0):

Well here's a way to do it, literally just extracting the algorithm but having the concrete classes be in charge of `new`ing the right Matrix.  I'm still curious if there's a way to do this so that the `new` is in the abstract class, but this seems clean enough to me:

```cs
// Partial implementation ...

public abstract class Matrix : IEquatable<Matrix>
{
    protected double[,] _Submatrix(int removeRow, int removeCol)
    {
        if (removeRow > size - 1 || removeCol > size - 1) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot remove a row or column " +
                $"outside the size of the matrix ({size})");
        }

        double[,] result = new double[size - 1, size - 1];
        int skippedRows = 0;
        int skippedcols = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x += 1) {
            if (x == removeRow) {
                skippedRows += 1;
                continue;
            }
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y += 1) {
                if (y == removeCol) {
                    skippedcols += 1;
                    continue;
                }
                result[x - skippedRows, y - skippedcols] = data[x, y];
            }
            skippedcols = 0;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class Matrix4 : Matrix
{
    public Matrix3 Submatrix(int removeRow, int removeCol)
    {
        return new Matrix3(_Submatrix(removeRow, removeCol));
    }
}

public class Matrix3 : Matrix
{
    public Matrix2 Submatrix(int removeRow, int removeCol)
    {
        return new Matrix2(_Submatrix(removeRow, removeCol));
    }
}

public class Matrix2 : Matrix
{
    // Submatrix() not allowed on a Matrix2
}
```